# What to name a class that acts as a container for a collection but isn't a collection itself?

Tags: naming, coding-standards, source-code

I have an object that acts as nothing more complicated than a data store for a collection of items.  I do this because it lets me bind the data to a single object, which I can store in the Unity (game engine) editor and assign to a bunch of other objects so they all operate on the same list of data.

I'm not really sure what to call the class though:

```
class NameNeeded<T> : // Unity stuff
{
    public List<T> items { get; }
}
```

I can't inherit this object from anything but a special Unity object, so I can't mask it and pretend that it's a collection itself.  There's some other bookkeeping methods, but it's basically a collection container.

If I treat it like a regular collection, I end up with this...

```
class Lobby
{
    NameNeeded<User> users;

    void DoSomething()
    {
        users.items.Whatever();
    }
}
```

... which I find unattractive from the double plural implying users is a collection itself.

Comment: If the only purpose is to comply with the requirements of the library you are using (otherwise, you don't need the wrapper), the words "wrapper" or "container" are both appropriate.

Comment: Or "Adapter" is a common suffix...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given, your class *is* basically a collection container and the mentioned bookkeeping methods do not violate the single responsibility principle, you could benefit from the decorator pattern.

With this approach you can:

- Inherit from the unmentioned Unity parent class
- Bind this class (assuming your unknown code is using abstractions and takes `IList<T>`, `ICollection<T>` or `IEnumerable<T>`
- Add some other bookkeeping methods.

Given your naming question, something like `UnityList`, `CustomList` etc is all valid.
You can even inherit, i.e. `class UserList : UnityList<User>`.

```
public class Lobby
{
    private UnityList<User> _users;

    void DoSomething()
    {
        // Using LINQ on IList<T>
        var firstUser = _users.First();

         // Invoking one of your bookkeeping methods
        _users.ExtraMethod1(); 
    }

}

public class UnityList<T> : UnmentionedUnityClass, IList<T>
{
    private IList<T> _innerList = new List<T>();

    // Use this to just create empty list
    public UnityList<T>() { }

    // Use this to decorate your existing list i.e. from domain model
    public UnityList<T>(IList<T> innerList)
    {
        _innerList = innerList;
    }

    public void ExtraMethod1() {  }
    public void ExtraMethod2() {  }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _innerList.GetEnumerator();
    }


    public void Add(T item)
    {
        _innerList.Add(item);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        _innerList.Clear();
    }

    // Removed other calls to _innerList for readability.
    // However, using ReSharper, the IList<T> implementation can be generated and directly delegated to _innerList.        
}
```

Comment: I like this a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using a name that a lot of JavaScript frameworks use nowadays. Store.
Its a store for objects of type T. To go with your example an userStore sounds about right. You could then write userStore.items.Whatever(), which I think makes perfect sense.